# Offset first line of a paragraph

Tags: html, css

HTML

```html
<p><br />1.2 text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p><br />1.3 text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p><br />1.4 text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
```

With above code, is it possible to get following output with text stacked line by line in right position same level indented from paragraph number?

[image: first line of paragraph is offset to the left]

Comment: Can you edit the HTML (remove the `<br/>` tag)?

Comment: Find the solution that works whether there is a `<br/>` or not at the beginning in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can remove the `br` tag, you can achieve this with the `text-indent` property (more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent))

```css
p {
  margin-left: 2em;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>1.2 text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p>1.3 text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p>1.4 text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
```

If you can't edit the HTML, a workaround would be to add `display:none;` to the `<br/>` tag. You can still add spacing between the paragraphs with `padding-top` and offset the first line left with a negative `text-indent` value :

```css
br {
  display: none;
}
p {
  padding-top:1.2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<p><br />1.2 text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p><br />1.3 text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p><br />1.4 text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
```

Note that I used `em` units to offset the first line left. It will adapt to the font size but it will need to be tweaked according to the font you are using.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not since there is no `:first-word` pseudo selector, but it's easily possible if you change the HTML structure slightly:

```
<p><br /><span>1.2</span> text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
<p><br /><span>1.3</span> text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text </p>
<p><br /><span>1.4</span> text text text text text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text texttext text text</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    line-height: 1.25em;
    padding-left: 2em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: justify;
}

p > span {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    width: 2em;
}
p > br:first-child + span {
    top: 1.25em; /* this fixes position in case the <p> starts with a <br/> */
}
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/bfa4w3nu/2/

Comment: The text is not aligning justified in the fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the hint, even though this requirement was probably more than secondary (judging by the chosen answer). I updated the fiddle and the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

CSS3

```
li {
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```